# Debugging webapplication stops often without breakpoint in ThreadPoolExector class

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am using eclipse IDE Juno Service Release 2. Whenever I perform debugging in my web application. Thread stops at a particular method call `processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);` in `ThreadPoolExecutor` class unnecessarily. There is no breakpoint at it. I'm not sure why it happens. It really annoys me to make it continue running everytime it stops. Can someone show me how to resolve it?

**Screen shot**

[image]

Comment: Can someone help with this? Its really making things very hard.

Answer (score 0):

This is an uncaught exception handler. 
You can turn it off to catch an uncaught exception in Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug and "Suspend execution and uncaught exception"

Comment: Thanks Steffen for the answer. But, i still would like to understand why is the uncaught exception thrown? I will try un-checking it and see.